# Derivative formula for L2 fourier transform

Tags: fourier-transform

It is well known that if $f(x),f'(x) \in L_{PC}^1\left( { - \infty ,\infty } 
\right)$ then $F\left\{ {f'(x)} \right\} = i\omega F\left\{ {f(x)} \right\}$.
The proof itself is rather straightforward using integration by parts.

How would one go about proving that if $f(x),f'(x) \in L_{PC}^2\left( { - \infty ,\infty } \right)$ then the same formula takes hold (in the $L2$ sense) ?

Comment: What is $L^1_{PC}$? Integrable , piece-wise constant function?

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear, it's the space of all piecewise continuous absolutely integrable functions on the real line

Comment: $L^1 \cap L^2$ is dense in $L^2$. That's how we define the Fourier transform on $L^2$, then we use the Plancherel theorem for showing it is well-defined, bounded and unitary. So if $f,f' \in L^2$ then everything works well, by  considering a sequence $f_n \in L^1 \cap L^2$ such that  $f_n \to f, f_n' \to f'$ in $L^2$

Comment: Is there any chance you can elaborate? I'm trying to follow but I fail to fill in the gaps in the proof